# JavaScript single argument or array

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript function which currently accepts one argument:

`foo(country) { ... }` and so is used like `foo('US')`

I need to extend this function to accept one or multiple countries:

```
foo('US')
foo('US', 'CA', 'UK')
foo(['US', 'CA', 'UK'])
```

Is any syntax/keyword feature for this? In C# we have a `params` keyword for this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a gather:

```
function(...args) {
   // do something with args
}
```

This is generally considered preferable to using `arguments` because arguments is a weird case: it isn't truly an array, hence the awkward old idiom you'll still sometimes see:

```
var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
```

Comment: It's called a "rest parameter," FWIW.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder indeed, I just find "gather" and "spread" easier to explain to people, especially since the same operator does two opposite things depending on context.

Comment: :-) Quite. (Psst, neither rest nor spread is an operator. ;-) )

Answer (score 3):

You could take [rest parameters `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) and flat the array.

```js
function foo(...args) {
    return args.flat();
}

console.log(foo('US'));
console.log(foo('US', 'CA', 'UK'));
console.log(foo(['US', 'CA', 'UK']));
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. `arguments`.

```
foo(country){
    console.log(arguments)
}
```

It looks like an array. It's actually an object with numbered keys, but you can still loop through it and get the information you need.

Answer (score 1):

`arguments` in function plays the same role as `params` in c#.

```js
function foo() {
  console.log(arguments);
}

foo('a','b','c');
foo('a');
```